# Can you import another script/module from a variable?

Tags: python, variables, import

Do you always have to "hard-code" imports or could you techically import for example another script whose name is inside an variable? The desired behaviour is:

```
var_my_script_name = "my_script"

import var_my_script_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can! just use the module `importlib`:

```
import importlib

name_of_my_module_or_script="my_script"

my_module_object = importlib.import_module("my_script")

# Can also import built-in or third-party modules
np = importlib.import_module("numpy")
```